# How to tell if a set S, spans a plane, a line, or a point?

Tags: linear-algebra

Okay, I realize this question has been asked a lot, but I am having trouble with it.

Look at this question for instance :
Determine whether the set $S$ spans $\Bbb R^3$. If the set does not span $\Bbb R^3$, then give a geometric description of the subspace that it does span.

$$S = \{(2, 0, 1), (2, 0, −1), (6, 0, 1), (4, 0, 2)\}$$

Answer: $S$ does not span $\Bbb R^3$. $S$ spans a plane in $\Bbb R^3$
Now, I know that the determinant is Zero, therefore it doesn't span $\Bbb R^3$, but how do I know if it spans a plane, a line or a point?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: never heard of "spanning a point"

Comment: @Peter I suppose the zero vector "spans a point" in some sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single non-zero vector spans a line.

If two vectors $a,b$ are linear independent (both vectors non-zero and there is no real number $t$ with $a=bt$), they span a plane.

To span $\mathbb R_3$, you need $3$ linear independent vectors.

In general, vectors $a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n$ are linear independent , if $t_1a_1+t_2a_2+\cdots t_na_n=0$ implies $t_1=t_2=\cdots t_n=0$. In this case, they span $\mathbb R_n$

Answer (score 0):

The points $(2,0,1)$ and $(4,0,2)$ are clearly linked, $(6,0,1)-2(2,0,1)=(2,0,-1)$ therefore:

$$\mathrm{Span}(S)=\mathrm{Span}((2,0,1),(6,0,1)).$$

Moreover, $(2,0,1)$ and $(6,0,1)$ are free.  Finally, $S$ spans a plane.

You can have an equation of $\mathrm{Span}(S)$ computing:

$$(2,0,1)\wedge (6,0,1)=(0,4,0).$$

Hence $\mathrm{Span}(S)=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3,\ y=0\}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^3$.